# Send current to LED only after a specific duration

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, timer

I would like to know how I could do this 100% with basic electronic components (Transistor, LED, NE 555, batteries...):

Count 2 minutes (exactly) Then after 2 minutes... the LED lights up
I know that with a NE555 you can make "ticks" every X seconds depending on the size of the electronic capacitor... But I want that if the ticks are every 5 seconds, it lights the led only after (2*60)/5 = 24 ticks of the NE55.... how can I elaborate this?

Comment: Ever heard of a digital pulse counter? You can get chips that do this.

Comment: If you want "exactly", then no, that's physically impossible. If you want "within specified bounds", then sure, that's easy, what are the upper and lower bounds?

Comment: The bounds are wait approximatively between 1 and 10 minutes (+ or - 30 seconds) then lights up a led

Comment: "Count 2 minutes (exactly)" That is very tight timing, is there some tolerance? The cost will go down as the tolerance increases. The 555 does not have the repeatability you need to accomplish this at zero tolerence.

Comment: @MatR If you allow some tolerance (or are willing to spend time calibrating to your heart's content) then a one-shot timer can be used. So can a combination of a BJT and a MOSFET (with timing elements.) You don't need a 555 and a counter to do it. If you are looking for good precision and repeatability and decent accuracy and good stability over temperature then cheapest would be an MCU.

Comment: https://westsideelectronics.com/delay-timer-ic/ that may help. Just add any switch: relay, transistor.

Answer (score 1):

An NE555 timer doesn't have to be set up to create pulses (ticks), it can be used as in a monostable mode where the output will be high for a set duration after it is triggered. This can be used to create a delay timer.

As an example, the old Commodore 64 computers used a 555 to create a reset pulse when the computer was first turned on. When power was applied a small capacitor would hold the trigger input low just long enough to trigger the output and reset the CPU for a time determined by the timing resistor and capacitor, then the output would shut off and the CPU would start normal operation.

You could use this idea to make a circuit where the timer output would go high for 2 minutes after power up and then go low after that, and use an LED driver circuit that would light the LED when the timer output is low.

This would light the LED 2 minutes after you apply power to the circuit, and a momentary switch could be used to re-trigger the 555 if you wanted to start the delay again.

Getting an 'exact' timing with a 555 is going to be depend on how accurate you want 'exact' to be. If you need it to be very accurate you would probably need to look at something using a crystal time base and counter.

I've put together a circuit to demonstrate this, and used the current source technique from [this article](https://www.electroschematics.com/extended-period-555-on-pulse-timer/) to allow the use of a small ceramic capacitor.

The circuit is powered by a 9V battery, which is switched on 1 minute into the simulation. At this point the timer is triggered by C3 holding pin 2 low for a short time until it is charged by R3, and the output goes high, turning off Q1 and the LED
After 2 minutes the circuit times out, and the output goes low turning on the LED.
It remains in this state until powered off or the timer is re-triggered. This is shown by a pulse 10 minutes into the simulation switching pin 2 low briefly. When this happens the LED is turned off for 2 minutes, and then back on again.

The voltage controlled switches in the diagram are just to demonstrate the circuit and in the real world could be mechanical switches such as a toggle switch for power and a momentary pushbutton for reset.

[image: 2 minute delay timer circuit][image: 2 minute delay timer waveforms]

Comment: What sort of R and C values would let you get a 2 minute delay using an NE555, after considering leakage currents?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Looking at the data sheet, the very first thing it says is 'accurate timing from microseconds to hours'.  Two minutes would be what, around a 1 meg resistor and 100uF cap? Add a pot to adjust it and you could get it pretty close. Like I said, it depends on your definition of 'exact'. 
There are ways to get more accurate long time periods, using a CMOS 555 helps, and you can use a current source instead of a resistor as in this article:
https://www.electroschematics.com/extended-period-555-on-pulse-timer/

Comment: Did you read the paragraph titled "The timing capacitor" in the link you provided? Large value electrolytic capacitors are not a good choice for timing applications with 1 megohm resistors. That's why the **circuit** in the link you provided was more complicated than a simple 555 monostable.

Comment: That was the whole point of linking the article. I have amended my answer with a circuit based on this.

Comment: Well, I was commenting on your original answer, and your original answer did not contain the link or the related circuit. So, it looks like my comments had the desired effect...you improved your answer.

Comment: Fair enough. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it with simple parts. Timing starts when power is applied. Replace R1 with 50K in series with a 50K pot (connected as a rheostat) and adjust the frequency at pin 3 of the 555 to 68.27Hz (= 4096/60sec) using a frequency counter. Or just play with it until the timing is close enough if you don't have a frequency counter.

You can use output Q1 to Q9 from the CD4017 for a delay of 1 to 9 minutes.

[image]

But this is 2022, and if I had to do this for some reason I'd pick an 8 or 6 pin MCU and write a very simple program. The on-chip RC oscillator on those chips is usually good to ~1% so a crystal wouldn't even be necessary to get 555-type accuracy without even touching a trimpot.